# Wizz Air insurance policy

Tags: insurance, wizz-air

I booked a flight and together with the flight, I bought a travel insurance.

However, I never got an insurance policy **with my name and personal information** on it: I just received the general terms and conditions.

Does Wizz Air not issue such policy at all, or is it just very well hidden?

Comment: WizzAir doesn't issue the policy anyway, since they do not operate as an insurance provider, they just function as a middleman. The insurance provider is either Chubb European Group SE or Chubb Insurance Switzerland, depending on your residence. Have you checked your spam folder, if you maybe got an email from them, which was flagged?

Comment: @dunni : bingo, it was in spam folder :D